# Xpath for all /p in a div but excluding /p/i that contain specific text

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

The following xpath works fine for me:

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="story-body"]/div[2]/p//text()').extract()
```

But I want to exclude a `/p` from all paragraphs that has a tag /i in it and that "i" tag contains a specific text like "Follow us on "

Something like `div[2]/p//text() [not /p/i/text() (contains, "Follow us on")]`

Please guide what will be the `xpath` for it?

Answer (score 1):

> But I want to exclude a /p from all paragraphs that has a tag /i in it
>   and that "i" tag contains a specific text like "Follow us on "

You were close:

```
//div[@class="story-body"]/div[2]/p[not(i[contains(.,"Follow us on")])]//text()
```